# Analysis Services Dynamic Security

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx

I am trying to get data belongs to user region only(Using SSAS Roles, Dimension Data). example - UserId - BISERVER\Yohan and he belongs to North Region.
i am using this query

```
NonEmpty
([Region].[Region].Members,
([Measures].[Measure_Name], strtoset("[ME].[Domain ID].&[" + UserName() + "]"))
)
```

but still data showing for all regions. How can i fix this

Answer (score 1):

First check the user role, it should not be the admin.

Secondly, try below script

NonEmpty ([Region].[Region]. Children, 
([Measures].[Measure_Name], strtoset("[ME].[Domain ID].&[" + UserName() + "]")) )

Let me know if it helps.